# When I post a http in wildfly, the response part of the body is replace by header

Tags: java

I have a strange problem in WildFly 12. When I post a HTTP request sometimes body is replaced by HTTP response header. Sometimes it doesn't.

**the error json data:**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M Expires: 0^M Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate^M X-Powered-By: Undertow/1^M Server: WildFly/11^M X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block^M Pragma: no-cache^M X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN^M Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2018 13:00:25 GMT^M Connection: keep-alive^M X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff^M Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8^M Content-Length: 1569^M ^M ationId":"61e1e1b0867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","value":"MU5123","startStationName":"上海虹桥国际机场","endAreaName":"北京首都国际机场"},{"shiftId":"6c874935c59e11e8a4f557d52226d05c","startAreaId":"61e1e1b0867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","endStationName":"北京首都国际机场","lineId":"336fb55d-cc7c-11e8-9ed0-00163e02896a","label":"MU5159","dispatchTime":"14:30","endAreaId":"61e1e193867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","endStationId":"61e1e193867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","startAreaName":"上海虹桥国际机场","startStationId":"61e1e1b0867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","value":"MU5159","startStationName":"上海虹桥国际机场","endAreaName":"北京首都国际机场"},{"shiftId":"6c874930c59e11e8a4f557d52226d05c","startAreaId":"61e1e1b0867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","endStationName":"北京首都国际机场","lineId":"9db7b2a5c5a911e89ed000163e02896a","label":"MU5331","dispatchTime":"15:00","endAreaId":"61e1e193867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","endStationId":"61e1e193867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","startAreaName":"上海虹桥国际机场","startStationId":"61e1e1b0867c11e8a9a81fbc702bb402","value":"MU5331","startStationName":"上海虹桥国际机场","endAreaName":"北京首都国际机场"}]

Could someone let me know the reason would be for this behavior?

Comment: Please do not link to images but post the actual error text.

Comment: Hi, It looks like I'm having the same issue.Check my question here stackoverflow.com/questions/53763165. Can you provide additional info for your case? Do you have any proxies? What does your app looks like? Is there any custom code that works with request/response directly? Can you reproduce  this issue?

Comment: Does this happen on latest WildFly (15) as well?

Comment: There has been provided some fix in Undertow recently that might be related to this, see [1]. Although, as no Undertow version with the fix has been released yet, you have to build one by yourself.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1457