# Weird request/response bodies in Wildfly?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nginx, wildfly

I've been having this weird issues involving request/response bodies in my app running in Wildfly. It looks to me like a buffer somewhere is beeing shared by multiple threads serving different requests.

Example of a request body that is supposed to be JSON comming from my app:

```
{TTP/1.0 200 OK
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=7200
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: 
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 07 Dec 2018 06:32:15 GMT
Connection: close
Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 17:08:34 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Content-Length: 570
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

"-","appliedMethods":[{"uuid":"ebe163d3-c14c-4664-96a1-de8be17d462b","method":{"guid":"631e552a-e86e-44dc-8f2f-14e5b9bafa63", ... normal JSON continues
```

As you can see the body starts with a normal `{` character but then it is overriden by a portion of raw **response** from another request serving some `text/html`.

Same thing happens with responses. Unfortunately I'm not logging responses so all I have is an image:

[image: Weird response body]

Response body was partially overridden by different response, only this time first character also got replaced.

My stack is:

- Client - angularjs 1.6.6
- Nginx - nginx-plus-r14-p1 (1.13.7)
- Wildfly - 10.1.0.Final
- Spring - 4.2.4.RELEASE

Other observations I have:

- I can only measure case with requests but the rate of this issue appearing is extremly low: 57 cases out of 37 806 125 mesages I have currently logged.
- angularjs does not seem to cause this because:

  1. I had the same issue with 1.4.
  2. I'm pretty certain that when request is overridden, that part it is overridden with, belongs to request from another client. Since this client couldn't have this data it must be happening further down the line.

As far as I know I dont have any "unusual code" in my app that can cause such behaviour.

Only thing that I have that exceeds the scope of standard `@Controller` stuff is a RequestWrapper that caches request bodies for logging. It is alomst identical to `org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and certainly has no access to responses.

P.S. Looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204962/when-i-post-a-http-in-wildfly-the-response-part-of-the-body-is-replace-by-heade) is about the same issue.

UPDATE: Nginx logs proved that requests come normal from client.

Comment: Does this happen on latest WildFly (15) as well?

Comment: I don't know. I only use Wildfly 10 and question I linked says that same thing happening with 12.

Comment: There has been provided some fix in Undertow recently that might be related to this, see [1]. Although, as no Undertow version with the fix has been released yet, you have to build one by yourself.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1457

Comment: @MartinChoma Thank you for the info. It seems that the issue was fixed by simply updating the java. I cannot tell for sure, but it was two weeks since the last occurence. I just wanted to wait couple more weeks before posting results.

Comment: @chimmi have you definitely solved this issue (by upgrading java/Wildfly?)
We are seeing the same issue. OpenJDK 1.8.0_191, Wildfly 10.1.Final, Undertow 1.3.15.
Extremely rarely (once in a ten thousand or so), a response output from server will be "garbled" - either HTTP headers will be repeated, or only a part of the body will be present.

Comment: I believe so. I need to verify what versions we are currently using. Your Java version seems about right although iirc we are using Oracle.

Comment: @Ivan Indeed, all we did was update Java, from 1.8_121 to 1.8_181 (Oracle). Wildfly remained 10.1.0.Final.

Comment: @Chimmi thank you very much! Interesting. We'll try to update to OpenJDK 8u222 (company's policy to move away from Oracle). Definitely a weird issue, I barely found even this thread, after intensive web search.

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this thread - updating OpenJDK to 8u22 didn't completely solve the issue, but it reduced it by ~40 times. There are still intermittent failures, however. Wildfly remained at version 10.1.0.Final. Maybe updating WF would completely solve it, but unfortunately it's not on our roadmap at this particular moment.

Comment: I'm seeing this same weird problem on WildFly 10.1.0.Final but with keep-alive connections (UNDERTOW-1457 talks about non-persistent connections). Does anyone who noticed this issue have feedback on a Wildfly update with UNDERTOW-1457?